How to reset Wordpress - Settings - General page, so the website can use HTTP only?
Explaination
In Wordpress - Settings - General, I have edited the
WordPress Address and Site URL
to use HTTPS instead of HTTP without previously installing a SSL certificate.
The hosting provider (grape.ca) does not seem to permit LetsEncrypt certificates to be installed, neither phpMyAdmin to be accessed.
Through the wp-config.php, I have manually done a forced http redirect with the following command:
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
Now the admin dashboard opens up, but when i go to the Wordpress - Settings - General page, it loops forever and does not open.
Question
In which file are the settings page saved?
How can i reset them to HTTP only?

The setting is stored in the wp_options table in the connected database. You can change it by logging into phpmyadmin and navigating to the table and then edit the field siteurl. See here for more details.
Instead you can add these two lines to your wp-config file:
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );

See here for more details.

At what position should i put the two lines? In the beggining, middle, end? They do not exist inside the wp-config.php

The position does not matter. I'd just add it at the end. @Fillo

I added it on the bottom, but the problem persists. It keeps looping. I have installed WP phpMyAdmin to access the database, but since it is not HTTPS it does not let me access it.

Did you keep define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false); in there?

Yes i did keep it.

Two things you could try: (1) Clear your browser cache and try again. (2) Check if your htaccess file includes any redirects.

It shows http only:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

END WordPress

I managed to find a way to access the database and reset the links to HTTP. To enter the settings, on wp_options,  i had to delete the: define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false); and the define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
